# Laravel, VUE3, Inertia - store VUE3 components data in database and display them

Tags: laravel, vue.js, content-management-system, inertiajs

I would like to discuss with you my idea and whether it is possible to realize it at all.

The concept is to store the page content in the database in the format
[{"Component name/path": “Components/HeroBlock”,
{"prop..."}}, …]
And then call this components in the VUE component of the page (while SSR Inertia is working)

With such a system in place, it would be possible to make a convenient system for managing page content and still have VUE-hydrated content.

Who has any ideas? And is this idea objective at all?

I’ve decided to discuss it with community of more experienced developers first. Wanna know is it worth to spend time developing this